AWS Aurora Serverless (Mysql 5.7) sometimes reuses recent deleted primary IDs
We have a table in our application in which users are allowed to delete a row from "staff_entries" table and the deleted row is also copied to another table (deleted_staff_entries) as it is (along with the ID of the original row).
On rare occasions, we have observed that if the most recent row gets deleted from "staff_entries" table (suppose the ID of the deleted row was 385) and later new row is inserted in "staff_entries" table, the ID is set to 385. This is not the standard behaviour of mysql. Usually mysql skips the used IDs even if the row of that perticular ID has been removed.
Do we need to use some DB setting to make sure used IDs are never reused even if the row is deleted?
Note: This is not easily recreatable. If we delete a row and insert a row right away, it does get the next number as ID correctly. But if there is gap of 1-2 hours sometimes newly created row gets ID of recently deleted row. I tried contacting AWS support but they just tried deleting a row and adding a new row, and informed the new row did not get deleted rows ID. So it was no help.
